# Spring web mvc, common clean url parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to construct a clean URL mapping inside my MVC application and I found alot of common urls like:

/SITE/{city}-{language}/user/{userId}

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{city}-{language}/user/{userId}", 
         method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String user(@PathVariable String city, 
                   @PathVariable String language, 
                   @PathVariable String userId, 
                   Model model) {}
```

/SITE/{city}-{language}/comment/{userId}-{commentId}

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{city}-{language}/comment/{userId}-{commentId}",
         method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String comment(@PathVariable String city,
                      @PathVariable String language, 
                      @PathVariable String userId,
                      @PathVariable String commentId, 
                      Model model) {}
```

Is there a way to auto bind the city and the language to the model automatically instead of @PathVariable of Filters, I think it make since as it will reduce the @RequestMapping function paramets count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a work around that serves my need, I created an abstract base class that maps the common params.

```
public abstract class AbstractController {

    @ModelAttribute("currentCity")
    public CityEntity getCurrentCity(@PathVariable CityEntity city) {
        //CityEntity via a converter class
        return city;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("language")
    public String getLanguage(@PathVariable String language) {
        return language;
    }
}
```

and now the two common attributes will be available in the model object

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{city}-{language}")
public class UserController extends AbstractController {

      @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String user(@PathVariable String userId, 
               Model model) {...}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to implement the Interface [Converter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) for each type:

For example

```
public class StringToCityConverter<String, City> {
    ...
    public City convert (String cityName) {
        return this.cityDao.loadByCityName(cityName);
    }
}
```

And you need to register them. One Way is to use the Formatter Registrar.

Some Registrar to register the Formatter

```
public class MyRegistrar implements FormatterRegistrar {
    ...
    @Override
    public void registerFormatters(final FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new StringToCityConverter(cityDto));
    }
}
```

and this register the registrar

```
<!-- Installs application converters and formatters -->
<bean id="applicationConversionService"
    class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="formatterRegistrars">
        <set>
            <bean
                class="MyRegistrar" autowire="byType" />                               
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then you can write your controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{city}-{language}/comment/{userId}-{commentId}",
     method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String comment(@PathVariable City city, ... Model model) {}
```

Comment: But still I have to put @PathVariable multiple times. I am looking for a way that can unify those common params (I want to remove them from my controller functions, and bind them to the Modal automatically !)

Comment: You will need this annotation to tell spring that this variable is a  path variable but not a request/command object. So you will need this annotation as long as you do not exchange the complete argument resolvers.

Comment: I agree with you but adding those 2 parameters for each single controller method is just not seems right for me. 

One way to do that is creating a special filter that pass those 2 commands variable into a request parameters, I am asking if there is a way in to do that.

Comment: @Ehab Al-Hakawati: I believe you try to make some small progress with a lot of complicated work, anyway I think it is an interesting task (from the technical point of view). May you should have a look at Spring 3.1 feature called `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. See Spring Reverence 3.1 Chapter: "3.1.13 New HandlerMethod-based Support Classes For Annotated Controller Processing" for an short introduction http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#new-in-3.1-handler-method-controller-processing